# Pass a list from a class to another form's listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, class, listbox

I'm currently working on my first real project, a gecko based primitive browser in WinForms (I'm a beginner, please don't be harsh on me).
The browser itself is in the Form1 (ablak), and when I click the history button, Form 2 supposed to pop out with a ListBox of the history.
I got mind blocked when I tried to figure out how to send the list from Form1 to Form2.
(when i tried it with a ListBox in form1 it worked)

Form1:

```
public partial class ablak : Form // ablak=Form1
    {

 // codes..

        List<string> elozmenyek = new List<string>(); // the history list
        public void elozmenyek_method(ref List<string> elozmenyek)
        {

            foreach (GeckoHistoryEntry _E in geckoWebBrowser1.History)
            {
                elozmenyek.Add(_E.Url.ToString()); // putting the urls into the list
            }
        }

        public void elozmenyek_gomb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            elozmenyek_method(ref elozmenyek);

            Form2.listbox_transfer.DataSource = elozmenyek; // when i click it sends the history list to Form2's listbox_transfer list
        }
    }
```

Form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public ListBox listbox_transfer;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1 = listbox_transfer; // puts the transferred list into the ListBox
        }


    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `Form2`? Is it the name of a class or an instance of the Form2 class (it looks like it's the former)? Then, pass the `List<string>` (`elozmenyek`) to a new instance of Form2, using a public property or method. But first create the instance (or an overload of its constructor, if you like this method). Remove this: `public ListBox listbox_transfer;` and this: `listBox1 = listbox_transfer` and don't use `ref` in the method that creates the List: make `elozmenyek_method()` return a `List<string>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now!! And Form2 is a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form1
public partial class ablak : Form // ablak=Form1
    {

// codes..

```
    List<string> elozmenyek = new List<string>(); // the history list
    public void elozmenyek_method(ref List<string> elozmenyek)
    {

        foreach (GeckoHistoryEntry _E in geckoWebBrowser1.History)
        {
            elozmenyek.Add(_E.Url.ToString()); // putting the urls into the list
        }
    }

    public void elozmenyek_gomb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        elozmenyek_method(ref elozmenyek);

        Form2 form2 = new Form2(elozmenyek);//Pass list as constructor parameter to Form2
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(List<string> elozmenyek)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = elozmenyek; // puts the transfered list into the listbox
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you :)